# Why is my case-insensitive order by failing to sort results properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, innodb

I'm using MySql 5.6.15 on Amazon Linux.  I'm trying to write a simple query to get results ordered by the lower-cased version of my table's NAME column, which is of type VARCHAR(100).  The table has attributes

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

But notice I'm getting different results and the only thing that is different is that in the incorrect results, below, I'm getting one extra column ...

```
mysql> select NAME, ACTIVE, ADDRESS_ID, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_ON, ORGANIZATION_ID, IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS, IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS, MDR_NUMBER from organization order by lower(NAME);
+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------+
| NAME                                 | ACTIVE | ADDRESS_ID | COUNTRY_ID | CREATED_ON          | ORGANIZATION_ID | IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS | IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS | MDR_NUMBER |
+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------+
| Billy Madison Elementary             |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 7788            |                            |                    0 | NULL       |
| Bradley County Schools               |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 8888            |                            |                    0 | NULL       |
| Billy Madison Elementary             |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 9998            |                            |                    0 | NULL       |
```

When I don't request that extra column, I get the correct results ...

```
mysql> select NAME, ACTIVE, ADDRESS_ID, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_ON, ORGANIZATION_ID, IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS, IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS from organization order by lower(NAME);
+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------+
| NAME                                 | ACTIVE | ADDRESS_ID | COUNTRY_ID | CREATED_ON          | ORGANIZATION_ID | IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS | IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS |
+--------------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------+
| Billy Madison Elementary             |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 9998            |                            |                    0 |
| Billy Madison Elementary             |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 7788            |                            |                    0 |
| Bradley County Schools               |       | NULL       | US         | 2018-11-29 22:35:57 | 8888            |                            |                    0 |
```

What the hell is going on here?  How do I return results ordered by the lower-cased name?

**Edit:** Create table statement from running "SHOW CREATE TABLE" ...

```
| organization | CREATE TABLE `organization` (
  `ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `STATE_ID` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORGANIZATION_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_ID` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ENTERED` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `SAMPLE_ORGANIZATION` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `USE_EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATION` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ADDRESS_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `LTI_REFERER_DOMAIN` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `URL_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_ON` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `MDR_NUMBER` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIVE` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `USE_EXTERNAL_AUTH_FOR_ADMINS` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ORGANIZATION` (`ORGANIZATION_ID`),
  KEY `FK1_ORGANIZATION` (`COUNTRY_ID`),
  KEY `FK3_ORGANIZATION` (`ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID`),
  KEY `FK2_ORGANIZATION` (`PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ORGANIZATION` (`ADDRESS_ID`),
  KEY `FK5_ORGANIZATION` (`URL_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1_ORGANIZATION` FOREIGN KEY (`COUNTRY_ID`) REFERENCES `cb_country` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK2_ORGANIZATION` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID`) REFERENCES `organization` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK3_ORGANIZATION` FOREIGN KEY (`ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID`) REFERENCES `cb_org_type` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK5_ORGANIZATION` FOREIGN KEY (`URL_ID`) REFERENCES `sb_url` (`ID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ORGANIZATION` FOREIGN KEY (`ADDRESS_ID`) REFERENCES `cb_address` (`ID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
```

Comment: hmmm.. ok, you are selecting from a view and the view has another joined table  with a column named "name" in it and you don't have any of that table until you include that field so the optimizer takes that table out of the plan and uses a different column to sort.

Comment: I entered "mysql> show create view organization;" and got the result, "ERROR 1347 (HY000): 'core.organization' is not VIEW".

Comment: drat... ok my guess was wrong.

Comment: Adding additional columns to your select should not affect the outcome of your order by. I would double check the table for corruption... also try surrounding `NAME` with `\`` delimiters, NAME is not a reserved word, but it is a keyword, and could be confusing the parser.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE organization`

Comment: @RickJames, statement is added.

Comment: I think the issue is utf8_BIN. I'd try use collation utf8_general_cs

Comment: If you used any of the `_ci` collations, you could avoid using `LOWER()`.  I see what is causing the misalignment in the output -- `BIT(1)`.  Is `ID` used for anything?  You have `Organization_id`, which could be the PK.

Comment: @RickJames, ID is the PK, yes you are right on that one.  Are you saying, like fifonik, that if we changed teh collation fo the table, the case-insensitive ordering would just happen automatically without LOWER?

Comment: The _table_ charset and collation are _defaults_.  The attributes on the _column_ matter.  `ci` means "case insensitive", so you can get rid of `LOWER` _after_ changing the _column's_ collation.

Comment: Ok I'm a little slow but I think I'm slowly catching on.  So right now the collation for that column is "COLLATE utf8_bin".  So should we change that column's collation to "COLLATE utf8_general_ci"?

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT (SELECT Name FROM t WHERE ID = 123) = (SELECT Name FROM t WHERE ID = 456)` (replace 123 and 456 with the ID numbers of Billy Madison.

Comment: You _need_ `LOWER` if you want to keep `Billy` and `billy` together since you're using a `_bin` collation for `Name`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be1d74e765f5e0293f4c72b44b857e3e. However the result you posted above is unexpected.

Comment: This seems more like a bug somehow.  I just don't see how including 1 column would change that sort.  I wonder if this can be reproduced on a 5.7.  Maybe try something silly like using an alias for the table? `select ..., MDR_NUMBER from organization t order by lower(t.NAME)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you posted is correct. I created a [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/664bf6/2) to try to reproduce your problem using the data in your question, but it works fine. [Comment out the `order by` clause](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/664bf6/1) and you get the bad result you show in your question.

Sometimes UTF8 strings look identical but are not. Have you verified that

```
select * from organization where name = "Billy Madison Elementary"
```

returns the 2 rows you expect?

If the `NAME`s are identical, there is no kind of sorting that would not put them next to each other. The only sort on `NAME` that is consistent with the results you see is one where all 3 rows have identical `NAME` values. You might run into this sort of thing in some context where strings are all converted to integer values and all the names convert to zero, but even then I would expect the ordering of the results to stay consistent between the 2 queries in your question.

There are number of obscure ways a query can be truncated, and I would guess that the most likely explanation of what you are seeing is that the `order by` clause in the first query is not making it to the server. How are you issuing the query? Have you tried using a (different) interactive way to run the query? What if you keep the `MDR_NUMBER` column but omit the `IMPORT_ADMIN_DATA_FROM_SIS` column in your query?

Can you reproduce the problem using sqlfiddle.com? If so, please add the link to your question.

Comment: What about the contention in the comments that I don't need to use LOWER or UPPER to do case insensitive searches provided my column has a cretain collation?  Is taht true?

Comment: @Dave, sort order is determined by the collation applied. If you specify a case insensitive collation, then you do not need to use `lower`.  See the [MySql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset.html) for more information.

Comment: What collation do I need to specify so that I don't have to specify LOWER or UPPER?  Answering that will effectively solve the quesiton.

Comment: @Dave, although there are tons of character sets and collations to use for different situations, a good default and what I would recommend for you, since you seem to be using English only, is character set `utf8` and collation `utf8_general_ci`, where the "ci" stands for "case insensitive". More correct for multi-lingual applications would be `utf8_unicode_ci `. See the [MySql Documentation on Unicode Character Sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried "ALTER TABLE organization CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8_unicode_ci;" but got the error (for both character sets), "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown character set: 'utf8_unicode_ci'"

Comment: @Dave, the character set you want is `utf8`. `utf8_unicode_ci` is the _collation_ you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use lower on the order by statement, that's default for MySQL. Aside from that, I've never seen such bug... Maybe to removing the lower function from the order by and see if it fixes it...

From MySQL docs:
On character type columns, sorting—like all other comparison operations—is normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion. This means that the order is undefined for columns that are identical except for their case. You can force a case-sensitive sort for a column by using BINARY like so: ORDER BY BINARY col_name.

Comment: Where is your reference from the docs coming from?  Is it coming from the version fo MySQL that I'm running?

Answer (score 0):

Column selection shouldn't be the problem here. I am not sure how 'Bradley County Schools' comes in-between. However, if case sensitivity is the problem then you can use BINARY Operator. It forces the string comparison to be byte by byte instead of character by character. Find more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary)